# Azure Integration with REST API servicenow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, integration, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Guys in my previous attempt i have Integrated Servicenow with Azure DevOps, where based on the tickets generated in service now, work items are created in VSTS Board.
For e.g.  Incident(ticket in service now) is created with details, we would create work item on vsts board with same details as incident and we are successful.

Now the challenge is other way around where if we create or update something in VSTS Board it should create or update in Servicenow . Basically Bi- diretional. Servicenow has REST API Endpoints

so can any one pls suggest where would I put those endpoints in azure vsts board so tht i link them, or pls suggest me the correct path forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ServiceNow , it  provides Azure DevOps Integration (e.g. Microsoft [Azure DevOps Integration for Agile Development](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-it-business-management/page/product/agile-azure-integration/concept/agile-azure-integration-overview.html)). It can support synchronization of azure devops and servicenow.

But in Azure Devops, I am afraid that there is **no** such integrated tool or extension to achieve this function.

Generally, we need to use third-party tools to achieve this (azure devops update -> servicenow update).

As Amandeep Modgil said, Azure Logic App is a method.

For example(azure devops--> servicenow):

[image]

On the other hand, you could use [Zapier Service hook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.services-zapier) (This extension is pre-installed) in `Azure Devops -> Project Settings ->Service Hooks`. This tool also has the similar feature. But before creating a service hook, you need to create a subscription in Zapier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure logic apps for bidirectional service now integration.
Have a look at the following document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/service-now/

You can also make it work using power-flow if you are not interested in using logic apps, somewhat same concept.

here is an example workflow in logic apps.
At the end of this workflow you can write an expression to compare list from AzureDevops and ServiceNow and submit the exceptions to service now to create a ticket. Almost zero code expect the expression writing.

[image: LogicApps Snapshot]

Comment: .....i already ahve a conneciton set up from servicenow to azuredevops.....now i just need connection from azure--> servicenow...is it possible to have a quick call with you if you are comfortable

Comment: guys ZAIPIER work like a charm and its very easy....but my issue is to update on the same id...ZAPIER creates a different id altogether, for e.g.   If  i create a ticket is service now it should create a work item in azure, but if i make changes on the SAME work item it should reflect in snow as well...to achieve tht it should use the same id  in response of the rest msg..how can this be achieved